# How do I get Quicksilver to search my Chrome bookmarks?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, quicksilver

I'm on a Mac, and I've been using Quicksilver and Chrome as my browser.

I'm wondering if there's a way I use Quicksilver to open commonly used web sites.  For me this will include Google Finance, Google Mail, Pandora, FaceBook, and a few others.  I know there's a Safari plug-in, but I was wondering:  Is there a way to make it work with Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's ok for you to have your bookmarks synced to Safari (e.g. via XMarks), you could also use [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/). The bookmarks will be opened in your default browser (Chrome) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ferro, a Chrome extension that functions similarly to Quicksilver. It searches bookmarks, history, and open tabs, and has a lot of other functionality: [getferro.com](http://www.getferro.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can import your bookmarks into Safari and have QS index the Safari bookmarks. They get opened by the default browser.